# with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is not working / without is working

Tags: php, curl

this code seems to work, because the webpage responds "thank you for submission"

```
$url = "http://www.mamamia.gr/diag_v/index.php?name=James&eponimo=Vasdanoi&age=34&email=ddd401@gmail.com&thl=4747428928"
$ch = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

but the following code i think does not work because web page does not respond anything

```
$url = "http://www.mamamia.gr/diag_v/index.php"    
$fields_string = 'name=James&eponimo=Vasdanoi&age=34&email=ddd401@gmail.com&thl=4747428928'; 
$ch = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$output=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

can you advice?

Comment: That page only support GET method

Comment: thnaks for your reply. can you exlplain? or send me a link to understand what this means?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="formcheck" action="index.php" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);">
```

Because the form does not have a method="post" it does a GET rather than a POST

The method specifies how the web server will receive the submitted data.

---

Possibly the age should be `age=31-45` rather than 'age=34'
Possible you should add:

 
 
'&diaf=Mamamia' to the url

```
...thl=4747428928&diaf=Mamamia&diagon=&diaff=
```

But both routines returned a page:

**First Routine:**
[image]

**Second Routine:**
[image]

Comment: yes age=31-45 is the correct but this is not the matter.

Comment: check the 2 returned pages. The first says with bold charachters "Thank you for participating". the second does not. :-)